# Can count() be used in case statement?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have copied data from a csv file to table, `stage_table` with columns:

```
aid
a_name
addrid
addr1
addr2
city
pstate
country
postalcd
contactnumber
attendancekey
attendancedate
attendedyesno
action_indicator
```

I tried to make my `action_indicator` column in the table as 'Y' (by default the column is set to 'N') when `aid` in same table exists more than once.

I tried this query but doesn't work

```
update_address_query = ("update public.address set active_ind=case    
                         when count(aid)>1 then 'Y' end from address")    
cur.execute(update_address_query)
```

I am receiving error as:

> psycopg2.errors.DuplicateAlias: table name "address" specified more than once

Can this be rectified in any other way?

The columns in this address table are

> addrid
>
> addr1
>
> addr2
>
> city
>
> pstate
>
> country
>
> postalcd
>
> contactnumber
>
> active_indicator

The sample output should be like:

> 99801,No-13 4rthcrossst,GandiNagar,Bangalore,Karnataka,India,456009,7800912345,N
>
> 99802,No-14 5thcrossst,NehruNagar,Hyderabad,Telangana,India,556001,6800612345,N
>
> 99803,No-15 6thcrossst,SardarNagar,Ahmedabad,Gujarat,India,356009,9800912345,N
>
> 99804,No-16 7thcrossst,PatelNagar,Bangalore,Karnataka,India,456009,5800912345,N
>
> 99805,No-17 8thcrossst,AnnaNagar,Chennai,TamilNadu,India,456009,4800912345,N
>
> 99801,No-13 4rthcrossst,GandiNagar,Bangalore,Karnataka,India,456009,7800912345,Y
>
> 99802,No-14 5thcrossst,NehruNagar,Hyderabad,Telangana,India,556001,6800612345,Y
>
> 99803,No-15 6thcrossst,SardarNagar,Ahmedabad,Gujarat,India,356009,9800912345,Y
>
> 99804,No-16 7thcrossst,PatelNagar,Bangalore,Karnataka,India,456009,5800912345,Y
>
> 99805,No-17 8thcrossst,AnnaNagar,Chennai,TamilNadu,India,456009,4800912345,Y
>
> 99801,No-13 4rthcrossst,GandiNagar,Bangalore,Karnataka,India,456009,7800912345,Y
>
> 99802,No-14 5thcrossst,NehruNagar,Hyderabad,Telangana,India,556001,6800612345,Y
>
> 99803,No-15 6thcrossst,SardarNagar,Ahmedabad,Gujarat,India,356009,9800912345,Y
>
> 99804,No-16 7thcrossst,PatelNagar,Bangalore,Karnataka,India,456009,5800912345,Y
>
> 99805,No-17 8thcrossst,AnnaNagar,Chennai,TamilNadu,India,456009,4800912345,Y

Comment: Yes, but not in an `update` query.

Comment: can you please help me out in that case?

Answer (score 3):

If I get this right you want to set `active_ind` to 'Y' if and only if the `aid` in the same row exists more than once in the table. You could use a correlated subquery for getting the `count()`.

```
UPDATE public.address a1
       SET active_ind = CASE
                          WHEN (SELECT count(*)
                                       FROM public.address a2
                                       WHERE a2.aid = a1.aid) > 1 THEN
                            'Y'
                        END;
```

And by the way: It's a `CASE` **expression**, not a statement.

---

Edit:

If you don't want to touch the `active_ind` of the other rows you can also add such a subquery in a `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE public.address a1
       SET active_ind = 'Y'
       WHERE (SELECT count(*)
                     FROM public.address a2
                     WHERE a2.aid = a1.aid) > 1;
```

Comment: This is making all my rows to Y but I want only the repeated aid's to be made as Y @sticky bit

Comment: @anonymus: Whatever "repeated aid's" mean... Have a look at the edit if this is what you want. If not, I think it's best if you [edit] the question and add sample data and the desired result with that sample data to clarify what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-window.html) using `row_number()`:

```sql
with sub as (
   select *, 
          row_number() over(partition by aid order by pk_id) AS rn  --- USE PRIMARY KEY
   from public.address
)

update public.address a
set active_ind = 'Y'
from sub
where a.pk_id = sub.pk_id        --- USE UNIQUE IDENTIFIER OR PRIMARY KEY
  and sub.rn > 1
```

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/VAYU6471)</kbd>

Comment: window functions are not allowed in WHERE @Parfait

Comment: Indeed. See adjustment using CTE.

Comment: I don't know why its making all my records to 'Y' @Parfait

Comment: Without reproducible example I cannot check for you. Are you using primary key as indicated? See posted demo and how `Y` is assigned to non-first instances.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't correspond to your desired output. All your records are updated because all of your records have duplicates on `aid`. 
So this situation looks like the design of the database problem. If your version of Postgres is less than 12(current) you can try using `OIDS` column to find the oldest rows and mark them with 'N' as `active_indicator`. The rest will be marked with 'Y'. 
Code will look something like this:

```
UPDATE test_so SET active_indicator = 'Y';

UPDATE test_so SET active_indicator = 'N'
FROM (SELECT *, oid, row_number() over (partition by addrid order by oid) AS rank
        FROM test_so) a
WHERE a.rank = 1
AND test_so.oid = a.oid;
```

But it is much better to use timestamps for this purpose.

Comment: But doesn't it give a.oid ambigious ?? @zhuk

Comment: No, it doesn't. There are no OIDS except for test_so table